# Using MySQL to TRIM and SUBSTRING_ INDEX to remove all characters to the right

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a MySql table called widgets_items_model and in that table there is a column called notes.  I want to 
remove everything to the right of YYYY from only the records that have the following string in them:

This clients tracking number --  YYYYNNAA:  2015BA99 Project578

I have this SQL code that so far:

```
UPDATE widgets_items_model SET notes = TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(notes, 'YYYY', -1) FROM notes);
```

When I run the SQL it removes everything to the right of YYYY but it also empties every  'notes' field except for
the ones I wanted to trim.   For the fields I wanted to TRIM it does exactly what I wanted but all other notes fields data is being deleted instead of being left undisturbed.

How can I format the SQL so it trims everything to the right of YYY and does not empty the other fields 'notes' data?

Answer (score 0):

You can update only the fields with YYYY by using

```
UPDATE widgets_items_model SET notes = TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(notes, 'YYYY', -1) FROM notes) WHERE notes LIKE '%YYYY%';
```

Comment: Yes!  That works.**Thank you** so much Tdelang.  You made my day and saved me from wasting many additional hours.  *bowing*